# Detect another process's bitness (in Windows)

Tags: windows, x86, 64-bit, detect

How can I detect whether another process is running as 32/64 bit in Windows? I know how to do this for my own process, but not for a different process. A tip or solution in any language would be fine. Thanks!

Comment: What another process does is none of your bitness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [IsWow64Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Perfect - just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP SP2 also has *IsWow64Process()*. So, you can't have the guarantee that you are working under Windows 64-bits when you find *IsWow64Process()* in kernel32.dll.

It means that you cannot say anything when you get FALSE as result. You have to know the OS bitness or your process bitness to decide how to interpret FALSE.