# Get bitness (32-bit/64-bit) from Process object

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, process

> **Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell if another process is 64bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518053/how-can-i-tell-if-another-process-is-64bit)

Can I detect the bitness of a process from a .net Process object?  I'm not trying to detect the bitness of the running application, nor of the OS, but of a specific process where I have an active Process object that is tracking/associated with the process.

**Edit**
Looking for a solution without pinvoke

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know a process is 32-bit or 64-bit programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1953377/113116) and [Detect another process's bitness (in Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1095085/113116)

Comment: @Helen - The linked solutions use pinvoke.  Ideally there is a .net native way to gather this information from the Process object.

Comment: All - this is not an exact duplicate of the linked questions.  The referenced questions use pinvoke - that's sort of cheating, and my question is specific to gleaning information from the .net Process object.

Comment: See also [How to determine whether a System.Diagnostics.Process is 32 or 64 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3575785/113116)

Comment: @Gabe - yup...duplicate!  lets close this out.

Comment: All - I close this out.  Thanks to Gabe for digging up the duplicate.

Comment: @Blindy - what (which noun) would you say instead of "bitness"? Just curious.

Comment: @TonyCool, I would say "word size" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your bitness you will have to call some native methods. A good writeup on how to do this can be found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net/1840313#1840313)

Comment: so there's is absolutely no .net native way to do this in .net 4?

Comment: The OP is asking about **another process's bitness**, not the OS bitness.

Comment: @Helen - True but the methods take any process object so you can just as easily pass it the Process of the thing you care about